# java password field : dot code

Tags: java, jpasswordfield

Is there a code for the basic dot in password fields ? This one : [dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jObNL.png)

I have a button that shows the password (with setEchoChar()), but it's ugly if i put stars (*) when the user hide again the password.

Thanks.
(and btw first post, so if there is something I should change don't hesitate to say it)

Here is the most important part of the code :
`if (getjCheckBox().isSelected()){
    getjPasswordField().setEchoChar((char)0);
  } else {
    getjPasswordField().setEchoChar('*');
  }`

Comment: Provide us with code what You've tried and we can manage from there. I doubt anyone will provide You with ready code... or write it for You ;)

Comment: I have my code ready and functionning, i just would like to know if there is like an ASCII code for the dot ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't look for an ASCII character because it's not an ASCII character but an unicode one. The one you are looking for should be [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) one.

Which can be set through `field.setEchoChar('\u2022');`

But the more reasonable choice would be to override the default one used by the current look and feel.

Comment: Ah thanks ! I was looking in circles. That's why I didn't find it.